# onmousedown event object behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>testing</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test">
            <script>
                var t = document.getElementById("test");
                t.onmousedown = function(e) {
                    if (e.button === 0)
                        t.checked = true;
                    else if (e.button === 2)
                        t.checked = false;

                    alert(e.button);
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If I leave the line `alert(e.button);` where it is, checkbox clicking behaves as expected: all left-clicks check the checkbox, and all right-clicks uncheck the checkbox.

If I remove the code `alert(e.button);`, then all of a sudden, a left-click will check and then immediately uncheck the checkbox, and a right-click will do nothing but open the context menu.

Why does this happen? and What can I do to make it behave as I described it in the first paragraph but without `alert(e.button);`?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`? A mousedown event doesn't cause a checkbox to change, only a "click" event does, which is a mousedown followed by a mouseup on the same element. The `alert()` would be disrupting that and preventing the default click from occurring.

Comment: nope, that still causes the problem unfortunately

Comment: You could try cancelling the `click` event. But (other than for interest's sake) why are you trying to do this? Changing standard control behaviour is confusing for users, and is an accessibility fail if the control can't be used from the keyboard or a one-button mouse.

Comment: @Manuel Why do you want to override the default functionality of a checkbox? Won't users get confused if they keep left-clicking the control and nothing happens?

Comment: @gyre this isn't production code or a code that would be published live on a website. What inspired this was a bug I was trying to track down in my original code.

Comment: and this shows why alert is bad for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try by separating click events to `onlick` (for left click) and `oncontextmenu` (for right click). 
Also remember `return false;` to prevent showing content menu.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("test");

t.onclick = function(e) {
  t.checked = true;
}
t.oncontextmenu = function(e){
  t.checked = false;
  return false;
}
```

```html
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>testing</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test">
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you but could you also explain why the problem I was having originally even works that way? What's so special about the alert command that causes such a dramatic change in the behavior of the script?

Comment: @Manuel please see my answer, I just added a detailed explanation to it.

Comment: Thank you, @DineiRockenbach. The explanation was a nice touch. I was looking for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Explaining the behavior

From [W3 schools onmousedown Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp):

> The order of events related to the onmousedown event (for the left/middle mouse
>   button):
>
> 1. onmousedown
> 2. onmouseup
> 3. onclick
>
> The order of events related to the onmousedown event (for the right
>   mouse button):
>
> 1. onmousedown
> 2. onmouseup
> 3. oncontextmenu

The browser "checks" the checkbox at the `onclick` event, and as you can see the `onmousedown` event occurs before that.

When the `alert(e.button)` fires, the next events' flow is interrupted by the message box, so the `onclick` event never happens, and your code checks the checkbox by setting the `checked` property. When you don't have the `alert(e.button)`, you code checks the checkbox and the `onclick` event unchecks it right after.

## Solution

> Please see [Ngoan Tran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569849/3136474), his solution is far better that this one.

One solution might be create a clicable `div` above the checkbox, although this may raise usability issues.

```css
.container-div {
  position:relative;
}
.clicable-div {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-div">
          <div class="clicable-div" id="clicable"></div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test">
        </div>
        <script>
            var t = document.getElementById("clicable");
            var c = document.getElementById("test");
            t.onmousedown = function(e) {
                if (e.button === 0)
                    c.checked = true;
                else if (e.button === 2)
                    c.checked = false;
            };
            //Disables the contextual menu on right button click!
            t.oncontextmenu = function() {
              return false;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```