# <!DOCTYPE html> causes onmousedown to fail

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Good afternoon

I have been working through the 'Ajax For Dummies Book' and I have been trying  the examples. Last year I did the html and javascript courses on w3schools. I have started the web services but I am finding it very confusing so I decided to do Ajax to try and get a better understanding.

I have come across a rather odd issue. On page 54 of the book is this example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript Event Example</title>
   </head>
   <body onmousedown="document.bgcolor='pink'">
      <h1>Click this page to turn it pink!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

My issue is that when I add  to the top of the page the mouse click does not work. When I remove it then it does. I added the  to the example because the W3schools html course says you must add it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript Event Example</title>
   </head>
   <body onmousedown="document.bgcolor='pink'">
      <h1>Click this page to turn it pink!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

I did a search on Google for ' causes onmousedown to fail' but I did not find anything specifically related to this. I did find this post but it is not about my query: '[onmousedown event object behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569722/onmousedown-event-object-behaving-strangely)". None of the other articles in Google helped me.

I have also done a search in stackoverflow but sadly I have not found anything.

My question is: Why does the script stop working when I add  to it?

Regards
Philip

Comment: Burn the book, now. And don't go on w3schools. I suspect it fails because you're telling the browser you're using HTML5, but you're using code from the last century. This works: `<body onmousedown="document.body.style.backgroundColor='pink'">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript change background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089414/javascript-change-background-color-on-click)

Comment: Does your first example really work? It doesn't for me. Also, `bgcolor` is obsolete. (And there's nothing wrong with using w3schools)

Comment: @ChrisG i have never had a problem with w3schools, but then again ive only used it for syntax reminders really, not for courses

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Granted, they used to be *much* worse. Still: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: None of your examples work. Both JavaScript and the DOM are case-sensitive. The old property was called `bgColor`, not `bgcolor`. If you fix that **both** start working. In any case, your book must be more than 10 years old and that's an eternity in web development—you'll make better use of your time with newer material.

Answer (score 0):

The  declaration is used so that the browser knows which version oh html you are using it is not a html tag.

For example, suppose you are using HTML 4 then  refers to DTD, DTD specifies the rules for markup languages for html4 so that browser works correctly.

So in your case the function/property "onmousedown" you are using may not be recognizable by the browser and browser would have been stuck to default html format. so when you write  browser recognizes you html version and then renders the data.

Comment: The DOCTYPE declaration (or lack of) can certainly affect rendering but I'm not aware of any specific restriction when it comes to scripting. You can even use HTML5 data attributes successfully with HTML4 declaration.